# _queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescType error training SVM using BoW of ORB features

Tags: python, image-processing, svm, training-data, orb

I am training an SVM using the ORB descriptor next to BOW, however when I execute it I receive the following error

> "return bowDiction.compute (gray, orb.detect (gray))
>   cv2.error: OpenCV (3.4.5) D: \ Build \ OpenCV \ opencv-3.4.5 \ modules \ features2d \ src \ matchers.cpp: 753: error: (-215: Assertion failed) _queryDescriptors.type () = = trainDescType in function 'cv :: BFMatcher :: knnMatchImpl' "

What I understand is that the error occurs because the query descriptor and train descriptor does not have the same type, however I can not find a way to correct it.

```py
for p in training_paths:
    image = cv2.imread(p)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Initiate STAR detector
    orb = cv2.ORB_create() 
    # find the keypoints with ORB
    kp = orb.detect(gray,None)
    # compute the descriptors with ORB
    kp, des = orb.compute(gray, kp)

    des = np.float32(des)

    BOW.add(des)

#dictionary created
dictionary = BOW.cluster()

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
orb2 = cv2.ORB_create()
bowDiction = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(orb2, cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2))
bowDiction.setVocabulary(dictionary)
print("bow dictionary", np.shape(dictionary))


#returns descriptor of image at pth
def feature_extract(pth):
    im = cv2.imread(pth, 1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return bowDiction.compute(gray, orb.detect(gray))

train_desc = []
train_labels = []
i = 0

for p in training_paths:

    ##Error Here

    train_desc.extend(feature_extract(p))
    if names_path[i]=='Accordian':
        train_labels.append(1)
    if names_path[i]=='Dollar Bill':
        train_labels.append(2)
    if names_path[i]=='Motor Bike':
        train_labels.append(3)
    if names_path[i]=='Soccer Ball':
        train_labels.append(4)
    i = i+1
```

After this, I hope to perform some techniques to evaluate the performance of the SVM classifier, I found the percentage of division and cross validation, however I do not know if they work in this case.

Finally, I would like to know what considerations i should have when training an SVM using BOW.